# How is C++ destructor executed?

Tags: c++, constructor, destructor

For the following code, why is "A is closed: 3" printed twice?

```
#include <stdio.h>

class A
{
 public:
  int a;

  A(int n)
  {
    a = n;
    printf("This is A: %d.\n", a);
  }

  A()
  {
    a = 0;
    printf("This is A: %d.\n", a);
  }

  ~A()
  {
    printf("A is closed: %d.\n", a);
  }
};


class B
{
 public:
  A a;

  B()
  {
    a = A(3);
  }
};


void f()
{
  B b;
}


int main()
{
  f();
  return 0;
}
```

output:

```
This is A: 0.
This is A: 3.
A is closed: 3.
A is closed: 3.
```

Comment: This has _got_ to be a dupe :/  But I can't find it

Answer (score 2):

If you're expecting it to print exactly once, allow me to introduce you to [initializer lists](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/initializer_list):

```
class B {
    public:
        A a;

        B() : a(3) {
        }
};
```

Currently, in your code, it prints twice because when B is created, all its members are constructed, *then* the constructor of `B` is called. It is printing once to construct `A a`, then it's printing again when you set `a` to `A(3)`. Initializer lists allow you to specify how each member should be constructed before the constructor runs.

**Additional tip:** The order of initialization of the members is only affected by the order of their appearance in the struct/class and is unrelated to their order in the initializer list.

Comment: I am not asking why "This is A: 0." and "This is A: 3." are printed. I am asking why "A is closed: 3." printed twice. It should be "A is closed: 3" then "A is closed: 0.", right?

Comment: It's because the `A(3)` being assigned to `a` was destructed at the end of the execution of `B()` because it was a temporary variable. The second print of "A is closed: 3" occurs when B is destroyed and the destructor of its member `A` is called.

Comment: Then order-wise, shouldn't it be "This is A: 0", "A is closed: 3", "This is A: 3", "A is closed: 3" ?

Comment: No. First, you're creating A when you initialize B, then, you're initializing an instance of A via A(3), so the constructor is called again, which is why you're seeing those 2 messages. After that, A(3) will be destroyed, and `A a` is destroyed when the destructor of B is called as it goes out of scope.

Answer (score 0):

because before b assigned a **new** value to a , it already had a value (an instance exists).
you are using the default assignment operator which just makes a copy of the temp A(3) instance into a ,the member of B, and that copy must now be destroyed.

When f returns the B instance it created gets destroyed and in turn destroys its member a.